# What is the different between method A call method B many times vs method B call itself many times (recursion)?

Tags: android, kotlin, recursion

**Approach #1:** Recursion

```
// Recursion
suspend fun findAndHandleFile(fileName: String, timeoutMs: Long, startTiming: Long, intervalMs: Long = 3000) {
    val file = findWithFileName(fileName)
    if (file != null) {
        handleFile(file)
    } else {
        val passedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTiming
        if (passedTime < timeoutMs) {
            delay(internalMs)
            findAndHandleFile(fileName, timeoutMs, startTiming)
        }
    }    
}
```

**Approach #2:**

```
suspend fun findAndHandleFile(fileName: String, timeoutMs: Long, startTiming: Long, intervalMs: Long = 3000) {
    val file = findFile(fileName, timeoutMs, startTiming, 3000)
    if (file != null) {
        handleFile(file)
    }
}
```

```
suspend fun findFile(fileName: String, timeoutMs: Long, startTiming: Long, intervalMs: Long = 3000): File? {
    var file = findWithFileName(fileName)
    while(file == null && System.currentTimeMillis() < startTiming + timeoutMs) {
        delay(intervalMs)
        file = findWithFileName(fileName)
    }
}
```

Currently, I use Approach #1 and still not see any problem with it (don't cause StackOverflowError)

- It works well during an hour

I want to refactor from Approach #1 to Approach #2, but still not clearly sure what it is benefit from it.

My question for above approaches when running it on Android app:

- is Approach #2 more effective than Approach #1? what are they?

Hope receiving sharing from people. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion carries the risk of increased memory use and risk of a stack overflow, unless you are using tail recursion. In Kotlin, for reasons I'm not sure of, you have to explicitly mark the function with the `tailrec` keyword to take advantage of tail recursion. I think your function is a candidate.

However, the point of using recursion is to make code simpler and easier to follow. Usually that means you are breaking a problem down into a smaller version of itself. Using it for a timed loop just makes your code more complicated, so this is not a good use for recursion.

Your code could be rewritten like this, and I think the logic is easier to understand:

```
suspend fun findAndHandleFile(fileName: String, timeoutMs: Long, startTiming: Long, intervalMs: Long = 3000) {
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTiming + timeoutMs) {
        val file = findWithFileName(fileName)
        if (file != null) {
            handleFile(file)
            break
        }
        delay(intervalMs)
    }
}
```

Also, you could take advantage of `withTimeoutOrNull` and a `flow` to make it (in my opinion) even easier to follow the logic:

```
suspend fun findAndHandleFile(fileName: String, timeoutMs: Long, intervalMs: Long = 3000) {
    val fileMonitor = flow<File?> {
        while(true) {
            emit(findWithFileName(fileName))
            delay(intervalMs)
        }
    }
    withTimeoutOrNull(timeoutMs) {
        handleFile(fileMonitor.filterNotNull().first())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, Tenfour04! It becomes more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach (#1) is not recursion. The point of recursion is not to call the same function from it self, it's solving the same problem but with less complexity repeatedly until you reach your base state. For example, recursion with the mathematical operand - !.

5! can be written either as:

```
int total=1;
for(int i=1; i<num;i++)
    total*=i;
```

or it can be written, recursively, like so:

```
private int recursive(int n)
     if(n == 0)
          return 1;
     else
          return n*(recursive(n-1));
```

What you are using is a delay mechanism to call your self if your operation failed. That's general use with no relation to recursion.

Comment: Thank you for clarify the point of recursion, Dan Baruch! How about effectiveness (such as usage memory) between Approach #1 and Approach #2 or the same?

Comment: Other than having approach 2 possible to freeze your application (if your file is always null) I don't see a difference. I'd go with approach #1 though, as it does not freeze your application. It does have a side effect of possibly being called multiple times from other class while also calling it self due to file not being ready, which might cause a lot of "instances" of the function to hold memory which can be potentially bad but I don't think that's a case you need to address

Comment: Ended condition is found the file or reached timeout. Approach (#2): I separate Approach (#1) into 2 methods (findAndHandleFile and findFile). 
So my question is: A calls B after a period of time and B calls itself after a period of time, are they the same in this context?

Comment: Theoretically, approach #1 can end up  calling it self indefinitely. Same goes for approach #2. Approach #1 waste less memory as you can end up with the following function sequence in approach #2:  findAndHandleFile Called findFile. findFile failed, calling findAndHandleFile  again which in turn calls findFile again. Meaning, for every failed attempt you get 2 functions in your memory instead of one.